# Use Excel VBA to Open Internet Explorer and Click on a Webpage Button

Tags: excel, vba, button, click

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to open Internet Explorer, navigate to a webpage, and click button on that webpage. The code I'm using opens opens Internet Explorer and navigates to the webpage just fine. But I'm struggling to get the code to click the button.

Any thoughts?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Sub MeethinghouseLocator()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/maps/meetinghouses/lang=eng&q=888+N+600+W"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
IE.document.all("search-input__execute button--primary").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `getElementsByClassname` like this `IE.document.getElementsByClassname("search-input__execute button--primary")(0).Click`.  Or, alternatively, you can use `querySelector` like this `IE.document.querySelector("button.search-input__execute.button--primary").click`.

Comment: `But I'm struggling to get the code to click the button.` - so what is happening? Any error messages? What and where?

Comment: The querySelector option worked for me. Many, many thanks! I wasn't gonna figure this one out on my own.